# Logstash unable to parse timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Unable to parse date from csv.

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"@timestamp", :value=>"4/10/2016", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"4/10/2016\"", :config_parsers=>"%m/%d/%y", :config_locale=>"default=en_US", :level=>:warn}
```

Code:

```
date {
    match => [ "@timestamp", "%m/%d/%y" ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date pattern should be

```
date {
    match => [ "@timestamp", "MM/dd/YYYY" ]
}
```

See all available formats in the [Joda documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)